# Node.js application connect to an existing website

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I need to create a node.js application which should do a login to an existing website. The app should enter user and login to the website.The tricky part is that the website is on the internet and it is not created from us, so REST api is not an option. Can you please provide me an example how should I do that, because I've searched multiple topics and haven't found a solution how to do it

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) help?

Comment: did you try doing a simple POST request in vanilla node.js? https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback